# -webkit-linear-gradient snaps to 90deg

Tags: css, webkit, gradient, linear-gradients

I came upon some strange behaviour in Chrome (latest) on Win7.
FF and IE10 work as expected.

Take a look at this Fiddle please:
http://jsfiddle.net/KrNm4/3/

```
.a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-85deg, #efefef 25%, #666 25%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-85deg, #efefef 25%, #666 25%);
}
.b {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-85deg, #efefef 15%, #666 15%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-85deg, #efefef 15%, #666 15%);    
}

<div class="a">a</div>
<div class="b">b</div>
```

The second div shows the gradient with a wrong angle.
I couldn't figure out when exactly it snaps to 90°. It seems to depend on the size of the div, however.

Anyone knows something about this?
Is it a bug, a feature, superman or am I stupid and just missing something?

EDIT: I just checked Browsershots, same result on Linux and Mac

Comment: chrome is too busy recording users behaviour so they cut down the workload of the rendering engine by rounding this kind of stuff

Comment: lol...nah really?...this can't be expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known bug. [Have a look here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162538). It's currently a priority 2 error among Chromium devs.